# SQL Select all columns from one table and Max value of another column on another table

Tags: sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

This is my first question in stackoverflow and I hope I get an answer soon to my problem. :) I tried searching for quite some time from other sources but unfortunately, couldn't find a working answer.

So, I am working on a project and since I am a newbie to sql, I cannot do this:

I have 2 tables:

"Customers" with columns "id", "name", "last name" ("id" is primary key)
"Sessions" with columns "id", "Customer", "entrydate" ("id" is primary key)

"Customer" from "Sessions" is tied to "id" from "Customers". (foreign key)

I need a query that returns all columns from table "Customers" with one additional column showing the entrydate of the latest "Sessions" record, of each Customer of course. "Sessions" table may have many records for an individual "Customers" record, as you can imagine.

Thanks everybody in advance and hope to get an answer soon.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be missing something really obvious but this sounds really really basic sql the kind you'd find in a sql tutorial
https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_groupby.asp

```
SELECT C.name,c.lastName,MAX(S.entryDate) FROM customers C
inner join Sessions S ON S.CustomerId=C.Id
group by C.name,C.lastName
```

Comment: Mark, you are not missing anything... :) We all start from somewhere, right? To tell you the truth, I managed to get it to work after some studying with a subquery, but your approach seems much easier. I actually tried your method before I list the question here, but my syntax was wrong and I received an error... Stay tuned cause I may need your help again in the future, hopefully for more complex queries. :) Thanx again.

Comment: Sorry @JohnKastana I didn't mean to come across like that but maybe you would benefit from following some tutorials maybe something like a simple shopping cart/ customer, order, delivery tutorial would help alot. The best advice I can give you when working with SQL is not to think about a single item but think set theory. Worth a google.

Answer (score 1):

Its as simple as that.

`SELECT C.id,C.name,c.lastName,MAX(S.entryDate) as lastEntry
FROM customers C join Sessions S ON S.CustomerId=C.Id group by C.id`